# How to upgrade to Rikulo UI 0.6.3

Tags: dart, rikulo

Trying to upgrade to 0.6.3, but Pub Manager updates nothing. If you checked the packages directory, you'll find it remains at 0.6.2+2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sicne 0.6.3, we rename it to Rikulo UI and the package is renamed to rikulo_ui. Thus, you have to change the dependencies in your pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  rikulo_ui: any
```

Furthermore, you have to change the import statement to rikulo_ui, such as:

```
import 'package:rikulo_ui/view.dart';
```

In the HTML file, you have to link the CSS file from rikulo_ui too:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="packages/rikulo_ui/resource/css/default/view.css" />
```

If you cloned Rikulo UI's git repository, you have to switch it to the new location:

```
git config remote.origin.url git://github.com/rikulo/ui.git
```